# Remove duplicates condition to column value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables - Table_1 and Table_2.

They have identical columns - Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4(integer).

```
Col4 value for all Table_1 rows is 1.
Col4 value for all Table_2 rows is 2.
```

I insert Table_2 rows into Table_1.

Table_1 and Table_2 have some duplicate values based on Col1 and Col2. I need to retain the Table_2 values and delete the Table_1 duplicate values.

For example:

```
   Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
1) a   ,b   ,c   ,1      (From Table_1)
2) a   ,b   ,d   ,2      (From Table_2)
```

I tried the following -

`ALTER TABLE Table_1 ADD UNIQUE (Col1, Col2);`

It removed the Table_2 values instead of Table_1 values.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Put a unique key on col1, col2 and use `on duplicate key update col3=VALUES(col3), col4=VALUES(col4)` when you insert.

Comment: What if there are already duplicates on Col1, Col2 existing in the original table which I don't want to delete?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative. Create the unique key on col1, col2 and use the [`REPLACE INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) syntax.

```
REPLACE INTO Table_1 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM Table_2
```

If a duplicate record exists, it will delete the record in Table_1 and insert the record from Table_2. If the record doesn't exist, it simply inserts it.

Comment: What if there are already duplicates  on Col1, Col2 existing in the orginal table which I don't want to delete?

Comment: Can you update your question to provide some sample data and the desired output?